# Rpi zero w is not recognized as com port

Tags: pi-zero-w, serial, uart

When I connect my Rpi zero w to my PC (windows 10 via usb cable, I cannot see it under com port devices of PC. I am connecting micro usb side to the socket labeled as USB on Rpi. I want to establish a serial communication between my PC (windows 10) and Rpi. Is not this such a normal thing that should work? What is wrong?

Comment: What have you done on the software side?  Bare minis to add something like modules-load=dwc2,g_serial into command line...

Comment: @Andrew from raspi-config I enabled serial interface, other than that, I have not modified anything. I can ssh into it by the way. I wonder why my w10 pc does not even see/list rpi under com ports when it is connected via usb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default serial port on the Pi is presented on the GPIO pins BCM 14 and 15 not over usb.

To create a serial port over USB you have to:

1. Set up the Pi operating system first on the SD card
2. When booted enable serial gadget mode on the Pi
3. Reboot the Pi

To enable gadget mode issue the following from the Pi command line:

```
echo dtoverlay=dwc2 | sudo tee -a /boot/config.txt
echo 'dwc2' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
echo 'g_serial' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

After the rebootyou will have a device */dev/ttyGS0* that is the USB port.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try these. However I am confused for one thing, I could make raspberry pi communicate with another microcontroller through that usb connection port. Rpi sees a device attached at /dev/ttyACM0 and I could use screen command to establish the connection. Is it normal to be able to do that with the microcontroller but not with the pc?

Comment: it worked... though I have not completely understand the reason why I could use the serial port to communicate with a mcu before doing your suggested settings but not with pc.

Comment: "understand the reason why" - because USB OTG

Comment: Controllers are configured to act as serial ports (normally in firmware on the chip) and have to be told how to act as a USB port in software.  The zero range is a Linux computer and brings full USB support from boot and has to be told its a serial port, Ethernet network etc.  To see more capabilities see https://gist.github.com/SeanMollet/67e2d3c7f49cdfee9c57542693e172f6  BUT note the os discussed is out of date